If in $\triangle ABC$, $r=1,a=3$,then find least possible area of $\triangle ABC$
A circle of radius $1$ unit is inscribed in $\triangle ABC$. If $BC=3$ then find the least possible area of $\triangle ABC$ and also find the perimeter of the triangle when it has the least possible area.
My Attempt
If $\triangle$ denotes the area of the triangle and $s$ denotes the semi-perimeter, then
$r=\frac{\triangle}{s}=1$
$\Rightarrow 2\triangle=2s=3+b+c$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t $c$ we get
$2\frac{d\triangle}{dc}=\frac{db}{dc}+1$
Now, I require one relation between $b$ and $c$ in order to evaluate $\frac{db}{dc}$
Could there be another approach to this problem

Hint: try using Heron-formula.

derivatives in a geometry problem seems overkill, think about incenters

Let the center of the circle $O = (0,0)$, $B = (-b,-r)$, $C = (c,-r)$, and $\beta = \angle CBO$, $\gamma = \angle BCO$​.
Let the height of triangle (distance between $A$ and $BC$) be $h$. Minimizing the area is equivalent to minimizing $h$.

By geometry,

$b = r \cot \beta$, $c = r \cot \gamma$.
$a = |BC| = h \cot(2\beta) + h \cot(2\gamma)$.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
h &= \frac{a}{\cot{2\beta} + \cot{2\gamma}} \\
&= \frac{a}{\frac{\cot^2{\beta}-1}{2\cot\beta} + \frac{\cot^2{\gamma}-1}{2\cot\gamma}} \\
&= \frac{a}{\frac{b^2-r^2}{2br} + \frac{c^2-r^2}{2cr}}.
\end{split}
$$
Let us maximize the denominator.
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{b^2-r^2}{2br} + \frac{c^2-r^2}{2cr}
&= \frac{c (b^2-r^2) + b(c^2-r^2)}{2bcr} \\
&= \frac{(bc - r^2) (b+c)}{2bcr} \\
&= \frac{(1 - \frac{r^2}{bc}) (b+c)}{2r}. \\
\end{split}
$$
Note that $bc \leq (\frac{b+c}2)^2$, and equals when $b = c = 1.5$. ($|BC| = b+c = 3$.) Now everything is clear.


Let put the triangle into the coordinate axes such that $B=(0,0)$ and $C=(3,0)$, then the inscribed circle touches $BC$ at point $D=(a,0)$ (where $a\in[0,3]$ can vary), see the picture. Let $b=\angle EBD$, $c=\angle ECD$, then $\angle ABC=2b$, $\angle ACB=2c$. Since $ED$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and $\tan b=1/a$, $\tan c=1/(3-a)$; consequently
$$
\tan \angle ABC=\tan(2b)=\frac{2\tan b}{1-\tan^2b}=\frac{2a}{a^2-1}
$$
and similarly
$$
\tan \angle ACB=\frac{2(3-a)}{(3-a)^2-1}.
$$
To finde the coordinates of point $A$, we need to solve the system of equations
\begin{align}
y&= x\cdot\tan \angle ABC;\\
y&= (3-x)\cdot\tan \angle ACN
\end{align}
which yields
$$
x=\frac{(a^2-1)(3-a)}{3a-a^2-1}, \quad y=\frac{2a(3-a)}{3a-a^2-1}
$$
We need that $x\in[0,3]$ and $y\ge 0$, so $a\in[1,2]$, and the area is
$$
S=\frac12 \cdot 3\cdot y=\frac{3a(3-a)}{3a-a^2-1}
$$
which achieves its minimum (not suprisingly!) at $a=3/2$ when $y=18/5$ and the perimeter in this case is $3+2\cdot \sqrt{(18/5)^2+(3/2)^2}$.

$\sqrt{(18/5)^2+(3/2)^2}$ is rational and evaluate to $39/10$

HINT.- Since area of $\triangle {ABC}$ is equal to $\dfrac{\overline{BC}\times h}{2}$ we can find the smallest possible $h$ and classic construction of the tangents shows that this occurs when $\triangle{ABC}$ is isosceles (in which case the tangency point is the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$). Calculation gives
$$h=\frac{18}{5}\text { and perimeter=}3h$$

Here is one way using Lagrangian. You have found out that $\Delta =s$. Using your notations, the Heron formula implies $(s-3)(s-b)(s-c)-s=0$. We want to minimize $s$. The Lagrangian is
$$L(b,c,\lambda)=s+\lambda ( (s-3)(s-b)(s-c)-s ),$$
where $s=\frac{3+b+c}{2}$.
After taking derivatives w.r.t $b$ and $c$, we can see right away that $b=c$ (They must be equal due to symmetry). Now draw a unit circle inscribed in an isosceles triangle and we can find the height to the side BC is $\frac{18}{5}$ easily.
